# When exporting `/dir` on `server`, is it possible to mount `server:/dir/subdir` using NFSv3?

Tags: mount, nfs

The title should say it all:

If I have a directory structure like this on `server`, and I export `/dir`, can clients mount sub-directories of `/dir` (like `/dir/subdir`) using "standard" NFSv3, or is that possible only when using NFS >= v4?

```text
/dir
/dir/subdir
/dir/subdir2
```

It seems to work with current Linux, but I'm unsure whether that is [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1813), or even whether the standard covers that topic at all.

Answer (score 1):

The standard defines the protocol spoken between a client (the mounting machine) and the server (the exporting machine). How the mounting machine presents something isn't covered – and in the end, mounting a subdirectory of an export is naught but a different conversion of paths relative to the mount points to objects requested over NFS, so not really covered by it.

Now, in NFSv2 and v3, there's the MOUNT protocol that is used to tell the server what you're intending to  mount, so that it gives you a handle for that. The MOUNT protocol spec doesn't define whether a server should allow subdirectory mounting either. (And as said, functionally, you could achieve the same by "actually" mounting the explicitly exported directory and just translating paths locally – if even just with a bind mount.)

Comment: Actually there was a "security" argument claiming that it's more secure to mount only a sub-directory of the exported filesystem, and I felt unsure how easy it would be to get out of such a mount...

Comment: in "normally implemented" SMBv3, you'd have to go through the MOUNT protocol and the server would actually have control over what you can mount – but I'm not sure how that would be more or less secure than the access controls you have anyway. Honest opinion, maybe a bit blunt: if you're operating NFSv3 in 2022, your focus isn't security but keeping a walled garden of existing infrastructure running. I'm at least having a difficult time finding a better reason to use NFSv3 these days.